# how to add a new field with a given condition in mongo db?

Tags: database, mongodb, insertion

I wanted to insert a new **field** to all the documents in my collection named '**students**' where the age is >19..but I am getting an error.

I run the following command:-

```
my_db> db.students.updateMany({age:{$gt:19},{$set:{'marks':9}}})
```

and the error shown is:-

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:37)                                                                                                                                                                                                        > 1 | db.students.updateMany({age:{$gt:19},{$set:{'marks':9}}})

Comment: Make sure to close the brackets correctly. Refer the documentation. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close the curly brackets correctly, change this to:

```
db.students.updateMany({age:{$gt:19}},{$set:{'marks':9}});
```